# ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta de no coincidentes?

Tags: mysql

¡Hola, buenas a todos!
Os comento, tengo la siguiente estructura en esta base de datos:
[image: imagen de la estructura]

Bien pues tengo que hacer consultas de cosas no coincidentes.
Por ejemplo, mostrar todos los campos de los clientes que no hayan realizado ningún pedido.
Sé que obviamente tendría que buscar en la tabla de pedidos en código de cliente los que no estén y luego con el join mostrar todo de los clientes, pero no se como hacer para buscar en pedidos si el código del cliente esta o no.
Me estoy volviendo loco para intentar sacarlo y sinceramente no se como hacerlo. ¿Alguien me podría guiar un poco o echarme una mano? 
¡Muchas gracias!

[Base de datos para importar.](https://mega.nz/#!22ASAKyC!n7OEc1H89YN1b18ex4M-fi9WFbFYzEswLG__iXGMr7k)

Comment: Tienes que hacer una resta con un LEFT JOIN o un NOT IN. No es complicado, pero tienes que ponernos lo que hayas intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Hola David. Muchas gracias. El problema es que no se que intentar, he estado buscando en el libro de texto que tengo y por google y no he encontrado nada o nadie que me pueda dar una respuesta. Y sinceramente no se como empezar si quiera, no se me ocurre ninguna manera de hacerlo. He modificado para que puedas tener la base de datos en un link de mega.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Éstos serían los clientes que no han hecho pedidos:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Codigo_de_cliente NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Codigo_de_cliente FROM pedidos  
  );
```

Si prefieres utilizar LEFT JOIN, puedes hacerlo así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientes.* FROM clientes 
  LEFT JOIN pedidos USING(Codigo_de_cliente)
  WHERE pedidos.Numero_de_Pedido IS NULL;
```

En ambos casos el resultado debería ser:

> C07 C09 C10 C11

La verdad es que no sabría cómo explicártelas porque, como me dices que estás tan perdido, no sé por dónde empezar. Te propongo que me dejes tus dudas en los comentarios para ir completando la respuesta progresivamente.

Genial que hayas aportado el volcado en SQL de tu dataset, así podremos realizar las comprobaciones con los mismos datos.

El `USING(Codigo_de_cliente)` es una forma abreviada de

```
ON clientes.Codigo_de_cliente=pedidos.Codigo_de_cliente
```

Son totalmente equivalentes, pero `USING` sólo lo puedes utilizar cuando, como en este caso, los nombres de los campos coinciden.

Comment: Muchas gracias David. Viendo el código, sobre todo el primero ahora todo tiene muchísimo mas sentido, en realidad es muy simple, pero sinceramente no sabia por donde cogerlo. Siempre en clase habiamos tenido mas o menos ejemplo de todo y con pensar un poco era simple modificar o que se te ocurriera como hacer X cosa, pero con cosas no coincidentes nunca habia visto nada y estaba muy perdido y ni buscando en google era capaz de aclararme. ¿En el ejemplo del left join el USING que hace exactamente? Me lo puedo imaginar, pero mejor que me quede claro a tener una idea errónea. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: Era lo que me temía: en muchos casos el propio código es más claro que cualquier explicación... :) Ya te he ampliado la respuesta con la aclaración sobre el `USING()`

Comment: Perdona David, puse la respuesta muchas veces porque por alguna razón se me estaba borrando el comentario, disculpa el spam jajaja. Mira, estaba equivocado con el que hacia exactamente el USING, asi que genial, un 2x1 de aprendizaje hoy. ¡Muchísimas gracias por todo! Y si, muchas veces el propio código es mas claro que cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Lo del 2x1 suena bien: ya sabes que puedes votar tanto la respuesta como los comentarios, además de validarla como ya has hecho ;) Las consultas son un mundo, envíanos todas las que te cuesten, será un placer ayudarte con ellas...

Comment: Sí, correcto, he votado todo, pero al no tener 15 de reputación no la cambian públicamente aunque si que la cuenten. Perfecto, muchas gracias, por el momento todo lo demás esta bajo control jajaja.